# Correct Kinesis stream principal

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

What principal should be used when specifying a Kinesis stream as a principal in AWS? Specifically I want to write an `AWS::Lambda::Permission` resource in CloudFormation: the lambda will be triggered by a Kinesis stream. Principal is required from [the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html)

None of these work for me:

- `kinesis.amazonaws.com`
- `kinesisstream.amazonaws.com`
- `kinesisstreams.amazonaws.com`
- `kinesis-stream.amazonaws.com`

I haven't found any documentation which gives a mapping of service to principal. I found [this page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/dev/iam-role.html), which shows the principal for Kinesis Analytics is `kinesisanalytics.amazonaws.com`.

I looked at the [AWS service namespaces page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html#genref-aws-service-namespaces), but it didn't have any information about principals. The namespace for streams appeared to just be `kinesis`, but that didn't work for me, as mentioned above.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Kats - I am running into a similar issue. How did you resolve this?

Comment: @activelearner have you checked my answer?

Comment: @activelearner and Daniel have you fixed it? did your tried my solution here under?

Answer (score 1):

The correct one is kinesisanalytics.amazonaws.com

Yet let me assume that you want to trigger lambda once a new record putted into kinesis, then all what you need is:

1. Create IAM Role with the following assume role policy:

   `{
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
           "Statement": [
             {
               "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
               "Principal": {
                 "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
               },
               "Effect": "Allow"
             }
           ]
       }`
2. Create an IAM Role Policy "to be attached to the Role created in step 1":

   `{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": [
       "logs:CreateLogGroup",
       "logs:CreateLogStream",
       "logs:PutLogEvents"
     ],
     "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:{aws_region}:{account_id}:*:*",
     "Effect": "Allow"
   },
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": [
       "kinesis:GetRecords",
       "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
       "kinesis:DescribeStream",
       "kinesis:ListStreams"
     ],
     "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:{aws_region}:{account_id}:stream/{kinesis_stream_name}"
   }]
   }`
3. Attach IAM Role from step 1 to the lambda function
4. Do lambda event source mapping "Add Trigger" with the following attribute:

   batch_size        = 100
     starting position = "LATEST"
     Enabled           = True

Comment: Where did you find this? I have been looking forever.